# CI pagination parameter keeps appending to base_url

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am implementing a list of rows with pagination using CodeIgniter. The problem is it keeps appending `&page=n` everytime I click on next page.

for example, initially if my URL is like

`http://example.com/search/?a=1&b=2&page=1`

and when I click on page two, it becomes

`http://example.com/search/?a=1&b=2&page=1&page=2`

I tried playing with configs but doesn't seem to be working properly. Is that something to do with `base_url`? should I dynamically create `base_url` string without last parameter `&page=n`? I thought it would automatically re-write it.

pagination configs are as follows.

```
$page_config['base_url'] = $this->config->item('app_root') . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$page_config['total_rows'] = $result['total'];
$page_config['per_page'] = 10;
$page_config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$page_config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
$page_config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect

```
$page_config['base_url'] = $this->config->item('app_root') . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Codeigniter pagination add `&page=n` with the `config['base_url']`
But your base_url change each time at different page

```
$page_config['base_url']='http://example.com/search/?a=1&b=2';//for first time and codeigniter added $page=1
$page_config['base_url']='http://example.com/search/?a=1&b=2&page=1';//for 2nd time and codeigniter added $page=2
$page_config['base_url']='http://example.com/search/?a=1&b=2&page=1&page=2';//for 3rd time and codeigniter added $page=3
```

Your base url should be fixed and not be dynamic.
It should be

```
$page_config['base_url']='http://example.com/search/?a=1&b=2';
```

you can do it like this but its bad

```
$page_config['base_url'] = $this->config->item('app_root') . str_replace("&page=".$_GET['page'],"",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Add base_url this type

```
http://example.com/search/?a=1&b=2
$page_config['base_url'] = http://example.com/search/?a=1&b=2;
```

Comment: Ok, I was expecting that would be done automatically and I am making some mistake